# How to load the most fresh image from a directory in processing

Tags: image, directory, processing, loadimage

Please, let me know how to get *processing* to load the newest image from a directory.

img = loadImage("pic1.jpg"); is the basic example

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want the running program to automatically detect the latest image you put in your data folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code from user2468700 and didn't worked so I jumped into the reference and ended up with something like this:

```
    void callImage () {
     File dir = new File(dataPath(""));
     String [] list = dir.list();
     img = loadImage (path+list[list.length-1]);
     image(img, 0, 0);
    }
```

It will load from the "data" directory in your sketch directory.
Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, whenever you press the mouse, the program looks into the data folder and creates an **array of Strings that stores the file names**. The last value stored in the array is the latest image you placed in the folder.

The String **sketchPath** stores the path of the Processing sketch you're working on.

If you need a separate folder for images, just make one and change the parameter inside the String path; silly example: String path = sketchPath+"/MyFolderFullOfImages/".

This method works only if you have numbered images, because the names are sorted by alphanumeric order. However, you can easily customize this program by adding a control array that stores file names you've already used and let the program load only images with new names.

```
PImage img;

void setup () {
  size (500, 500);
}

void draw () {
  if (mousePressed) {
    callImage();
  }
}

void callImage () {
  background(200);
  String path = sketchPath+"/data/";
  File data = new File (path);
  String [] list = data.list();
  img = loadImage (path+list[list.length-1]);
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```